# Elasticsearch autosuggestion based on prefix and also based on custom tokenizer

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, n-gram

I am currently working on autosuggestion feature using ngram.

I have below filter, analyzer:

```
"nGram_filter": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit",
            "punctuation",
            "symbol"
          ]
        }
```

```
"nGram_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            "nGram_filter"
          ]
        }
```

Now when I tokenize sample data `test_table_for analyzers` and search for strings *test*, *table*, *analyzers*, I am able to get the above record. Now I understand that tokens are created with the filters I have specified and hence it is working.

But I need to add another feature to this - I need to enable prefix filter too.
Ex: When I search *test_table*(10 chars), I am able to get results because max n-gram is 10, but when I try *test_table_for*, it returns zero results because this token is absent for the record `test_table_for analyzers`.

How can I add a prefix based filter too for the existing n-gram analyzer? Like I should be able to get results matching up to max 10 chars when searched(which works currently) and also I should be able to suggest when the search string matches the record from start as well.

Comment: any update ? Did you try answer?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. I will update once I try.

Comment: thanks looking fwd to see update from u

Comment: any luck, lmk if you need more info?

Comment: Been busy with other tasks. Might take some time to try this out. But I definitely need to fix this. So when I do, I will update here. Until then sit back and relax. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: sure, lmk if you need more info and help

Comment: not its been almost 2 months, hope you got time to test the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with a single analyzer and you have to create another field where you can create an [edge_ngram tokens](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html) which will be used for `prefix` search, adding the index mapping, showing that which also includes your current analyzer.

**Index mapping**

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "autocomplete_filter": {
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 30
                },
                "nGram_filter": {
                    "type": "nGram",
                    "min_gram": 3,
                    "max_gram": 10,
                    "token_chars": [
                        "letter",
                        "digit",
                        "punctuation",
                        "symbol"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "prefixanalyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "autocomplete_filter"
                    ]
                },
                "ngramanalyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "nGram_filter"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "index.max_ngram_diff" : 30
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "title_prefix": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "prefixanalyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "title" :{
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "ngramanalyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "standard"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use use `analyze` API to confirm the prefix tokens:

```
{
    "analyzer": "prefixanalyzer",
    "text" : "test_table_for analyzers"
}
```

And your token `test_table_for` is also present, as shown below

```
{"tokens":[{"token":"t","start_offset":0,"end_offset":14,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":0},{"token":"te","start_offset":0,"end_offset":14,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":0},{"token":"tes","start_offset":0,"end_offset":14,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":0},{"token":"test","start_offset":0,"end_offset":14,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":0},{"token":"test_","start_offset":0,"end_offset":14,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":0},{"token":"test_t","start_offset":0,"end_offset":14,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":0},{"token":"test_ta","start_offset":0,"end_offset":14,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":0},{"token":"test_tab","start_offset":0,"end_offset":14,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":0},{"token":"test_tabl","start_offset":0,"end_offset":14,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":0},{"token":"test_table","start_offset":0,"end_offset":14,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":0},{"token":"test_table_","start_offset":0,"end_offset":14,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":0},{"token":"test_table_f","start_offset":0,"end_offset":14,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":0},{"token":"test_table_fo","start_offset":0,"end_offset":14,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":0},{"token":"test_table_for","start_offset":0,"end_offset":14,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":0},{"token":"a","start_offset":15,"end_offset":24,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":1},{"token":"an","start_offset":15,"end_offset":24,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":1},{"token":"ana","start_offset":15,"end_offset":24,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":1},{"token":"anal","start_offset":15,"end_offset":24,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":1},{"token":"analy","start_offset":15,"end_offset":24,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":1},{"token":"analyz","start_offset":15,"end_offset":24,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":1},{"token":"analyze","start_offset":15,"end_offset":24,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":1},{"token":"analyzer","start_offset":15,"end_offset":24,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":1},{"token":"analyzers","start_offset":15,"end_offset":24,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":1}]}
```

Now, you can use the [multi-match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) query, which  will give you the desired search result as shown below:

**Search query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "test_table_for",
            "fields": [
                "title",
                "title_prefix"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Search results**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "so_63981157",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.45920232,
                "_source": {
                    "title_prefix": "test_table_for analyzers",
                    "title": "test_table_for analyzers"
                }
            }
        ]
```